# HorizontalScrollView children are shown outside

Tags: android, android-studio, horizontalscrollview

A HorizontalScrollView is placed so that it is **not** taking all the horizon space.

When scrolling, the children are visible even when outside of the HorizontalScrollView boundaries, on top of the padding, on top of the margin, outside the card that contains the HorizontalScrollView, on top of that margin and padding.
The children are added programmatically, an ImageView and TextView inside a vertical LinearLayout.

I expected views to be masked when outside the boundaries of their ScrollView parent, but this is not happening.
This is the code that creates the children.

```
int pad = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.element_margin);
int imageSize = Misc.dpToPx(30, this);
for(int i = 0; i < 6 ; i++){

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( 3 * imageSize, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    layout.setPadding(pad, 0, pad,0);

    TintedIcon iv = new TintedIcon(layout.getContext());
    TextView tv = new TextView(layout.getContext());

    tv.setText("ארוחת בוקר");
    tv.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small);
    tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.FontDark));

    //init image
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.breakfast);

    iv.setTintedDrawable(drawable, getResources().getColor(R.color.iconDark));
    iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);


    layout.addView(iv, imageSize, imageSize);
    layout.addView(tv, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    features.addView(layout, lp);
}
```

TintedIcon is a view that extends ImageView with a function that gives tint to an image using mutate() on its drawable.

Comment: can you provide some codes? so that anyone can help you... without code it will be harder to predict

Comment: @Kushal added the code that generates the children.